# how to build an apk file with react-native

Tags: android, build, react-native

The docs at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html make no mention of installing the android sdk. It simply states I should get the adb which I got from developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html. now when I try this:

`C:\Users\username\Documents\host\Node\worship_app>adb install com.app_name PACKAGE`

I get the error "adb: usage: need APK file on command line". So I try the react native route instead with

`react-native start`

which outputs one message forever: "Loading dependency graph, done."

So I go to another cli window and enter
`react-native run-android`

After saving the file `local.properties` in the android subfolder. That's when I get the error " The SDK directory 'C:\Users\nmeri17\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' does not exist.", which in all fairness does not exist. I guess it should be there if I've got android sdk installed but since it's not in the docs, I'm guessing there's another way to go about it. I've squandered all my bandwidth on this folder they downloaded when I ran `react-native run-android` the 1st time; I was redirected to http://services.gradle.org/distributions/. The folder is still there along with the unpacked zip, along with the thousands of dependencies they also downloaded when I ran create-react-native-app AwesomeProject. I realized what was happening to my bandwidth very late and shut it down but most of the files are still there. Can they be of any use to me? I just want to package the snippets from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/quick-start, setup, see what it looks like and start my personal project based on what I've studied. Is there no way to achieve this without installing the gigantic sdk (which i can't even afford)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install Android SDK, it is better to install Android studio it will install all required tool, like ADB, google services etc.
then make sure android studio and java is set to environment path.
then setup all keys and run

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```